# Must I initialize everything in the constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

I believe that anything uninitialized gets automatically initialized and that this is somewhat dangerous (and poor practice). I also understand that initialization lists are generally more efficient (and in some cases necessary), however, I wanted to verify some parameters via a function call, before assigning them to a member variable.

For example, using the typical assignment constructor, I'd have something like this:

```
class MyObj
{
    private:
        int one_;
        int two_;
        DiffObj diffObj_;

    ... // other stuff
}

MyObj::MyObj(int a, int b, std::string type, std::vector<double> params)
{
    one_ = a;
    two_ = b;
    if (verifyType(type, params))
    {
        diffObj_ = createDiffObj(params);
    }
}
```

---

With this situation though, how could I utilize an initialization list? I thought perhaps by initializing some of the parameters in the constructor and using a separate call to initialize the rest, but I am not quite sure if that is kosher.

```
MyObj::MyObj(int a, int b) :
    one_(a),
    two_(b)
    {}

MyObj::initializeDiffObj(std::string type, std::vector<double> params)
{
    if (verifyType(type, params))
    {
        diffObj_ = createDiffObj(params);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not "necessary" to specify initialization for anything. As you say, if you don't specify, then the members will be default constructed, which in many cases is just fine. You can initialize some members in the initializer-list and the rest in the body of the constructor by calling a member function in your second code block if you want.

Comment: "I know that..." always seems to be followed by a false statement

Comment: @M.M: "I thought that..." might have been better stated

Comment: What's your plan for `diffObj_` if the `verifyType` fails?  Does `diffObj` have its own default constructor?

Comment: @ChrisStathis: Would it be correct syntactically to have a list and the rest in the braces?

Comment: @M.M: Error out. a la EXIT_FAILURE

Comment: does `diffObj_` have a constructor that can take `params` ? It would make for tidier code

Comment: @M.M: In fact it does. I am just going to map the vector data into an Eigen matrix. This was just for an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would be perfectly reasonable. You can have an initializer-list and do some work inside your constructor, you do not have to pick one.

```
 class MyClass {
     public:
         MyClass(int a, SomeStruct b)
          : _a(a) {
              if (isValid(b)) {
                   // Initialize _b
                   _b = createWeirdThingFromSomeStruct(b);
              }
         }
     private:
         int _a;
         WeirdThing _b;
};
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was unsure about. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your constructor does not provide an initializer for a member, that member is *default-initialized*. For `int` that means no initialization at all; for class types with a user-provided constructor it means to call that constructor.

Ideally the constructor-initializer list should do all the initializing of members. Here is one way to do it for your situation:

```
MyObj::MyObj(int a, int b, std::string type, std::vector<double> params)
    : one_(a), two_(b), 
      diffobj( verifyType(type, params), std::move(params) )
{
}
```

This (ab)uses the comma operator to fit in the call to `verifyType` during the initialization of `diffobj`.  The `verifyType` function should throw an exception if verification fails.